# Update array from event callback

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have to update an array *(which is bounded in my html template)* from an event based call back function. But it is `undefined` when I access it inside the callback.

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    let consumer: string[]; // <=== Updating this array
    const realtime = new Ably.Realtime('API-KEY');
    const channel = realtime.channels.get("test");
    channel.subscribe((msg) => {

      console.log("Received: " + msg.data);
      consumer.push(msg.data); // <=== but "consumer is undefined here"

    });
  }

}
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
  <div>
    <ul *ngFor="let item of consumer">
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you test the API `get`call ? Does it returns an `Observable`?

Comment: @t3__rry How can I check it? I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `let consumer: string[]; // <=== Updating` this array outside of the constructor -> above it for example.

Then, remove the 'let' keyword and initialize it to an empty array = [];
Now you can use it in a template.

Comment: moving it to outside the constructor makes it in-accessible from callback

Comment: consumer.push(msg.data); // <=== but "consumer is undefined here" SHOULD BE this.consumer.push(msg.data); // <=== but "consumer is undefined here"

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing your consumer array.

Change this line

```
let consumer: string[];
```

to

```
let consumer: string[] = [];
```

then it is an empty array and you can push some data in it.

Regards

Comment: That was one issue, now it takes the data in it. But not rendering in html.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here:

1. `consumer` is not exposed by the component. It is available only inside the constructor. So you won't be able to loop though it in the template. Change it to a property.
2. `consumer` is never initialized. You have only given its type, but not assigned anything to it.

You can fix these by declaring and initializing `consumer` as a property:

```
export class HomePage {
  consumer: string[] = []; // Declare and initialize here
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    const realtime = new Ably.Realtime('API-KEY');
    const channel = realtime.channels.get("test");
    channel.subscribe((msg) => {

      console.log("Received: " + msg.data);
      this.consumer.push(msg.data);

    });
  }

}
```

Comment: missing this before consumer.push